# REGEX Positive look ahead in REGEXEXTRACT GSheet formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, syntax

I have a STRING which can contain 1 or more numbers. Same situation for words. I'm look for 2 uniques REGEX formulas (GSheets REGEXTRACT or MATCH compliant)

String :
"4 x 120g" OR "120g"

(desired) results :

Last number : 120
Last word : g

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12v5BgH9KwLeCPNEymbelvHmc4uMNDeGnnBgy2f2umww/edit#gid=985627632) to my headache

Comment: re2 regex does not support this feature. If you give the full picture of your problem I or someone else may be able to show you a workaround.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 I've rewritten my question as to be clearer. Thanks for your advice and please follow the link if you think you can help

Comment: @ztiaa thanks for your help please see the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in C2:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3; "(?i)([a-z]+$)"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks ! I tried to find the equivalent for the [last number] (because your way seems to be by far the easiest way) but didn't get it.
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3; "(?i)([\d]+$)")) doesn't work

Comment: @DavidABITEBOUL try: `=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3; "(\d+)(?i)[a-z]+$"))`